# SQL get string after second comma

Tags: sql, string, substring, charindex

I have string like this:

`'Ing. , Jožko, Mrkvička, Bc.'`

and I need just:

`'Mrkvička'`

Thank you.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, Mysql, Oracle, Snowflake, Postgres, Teradata, MariaDB, etc)? Are there other strings in this column that have different patterns. The pattern, I'm assuming from this single instance, is that you split this string by a comma, trim each element, and return the 3rd element. Does that work for all instances?

Comment: This is going to be ugly to do on SQL Server.  Instead, consider normalizing your data before you bring it into the database.

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL:

```
select regexp_matches('Ing. , Jožko, Mrkvička, Bc.', '[^,]+,[^,]+,\s+([^,]+),')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution. But it can be done like this

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX (SUBSTRING_INDEX("Ing. , Jožko, Mrkvička, Bc.", ',', -2),',',1)
```

It will give you your desired output

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 TRIM(value)
FROM STRING_SPLIT('Ing. , Jožko, Mrkvička, Bc.', ',')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) = 3 
              THEN 0 
              ELSE 1 END
```

The [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function will split your string on the delimiter of your choice (`,`), then the results are ordered on the rank using the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function and limited at only one result with [`TOP 1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=015fc83d0fa91ab44948cebf0ccde622).

This solution works for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql:

```
select substring_index(substring_index('Ing. , Jožko, Mrkvička, Bc.', ',', 3), ',', -1)
```

Comment: I do believe the second word in my answer specifies the dbms

Comment: Absolutely true. Sorry for bothering you!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer doing a regex as below

```
select regexp_matches('Ing. , Jožko, Mrkvička, Bc.', '[^,]+,[^,]+\s+,([^,]+),') 
from yourTable
```

Input :

```
'Ing. , Jožko, Mrkvička, Bc.'
```

Output :

```
'Mrkvička'
```

This solution works for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.